# Finding Fisher Information matrix for AMH Copula

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I wanted to calculate the Fisher Information Matrix for a bivariate AMH copula(with 1 parameter) which has Weibull distributed marginals. What I have been doing till now is that I have been replacing the u and v in the PDF of AMH copula by distribution functions of weibull distribution and calculating the resulting 5x5 Fisher Information Matrix by double integration. But this is where the problem lies. I have used matlab for all calculations and I find that the integrals are diverging. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong with this approach? I have tried another approach wherein I used the law of large numbers. That approach is giving me correct results, but not the earlier mentioned one.